# Not able to generate release binary in xCode 4.0

Tags: iphone, xcodebuild

I have a strange problem with xCode 4.0 to generate a release binary even I have stated "YES" to the release build property and "NO" into the debug, still debug binary is generated. Product is still red, so it means that has not been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I forgot to edit scheme. O mine. :)